# Is there a way to mark an attribute as conditional

Tags: c#, attributes, conditional-compilation

So, I was working with some attributes and then I realized it might be helpful for me to have an attribute that is conditional on whether or not I build in debug or release.

It turns out I couldn't find what I was looking for by searching google or stack overflow. There is an attribute called [Conditional] and there is a [DebuggerDisplay] but I couldn't find one that set an attribute itself as conditional.

The following link explains the [Conditional] vs #if Debug 
[#if DEBUG vs. Conditional("DEBUG")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788605/if-debug-vs-conditionaldebug)

What I'm looking for is closer to only preferably in attribute form.

```
#if DEBUG
    [SomeAttribute(...)]
#endif
```

I realize I can do a #define and then use the correct symbol which would stop me from having to #if debug all over, but I feel like there should be an attribute flag that I don't know about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends a little bit on exactly what you are trying to achieve.

If you are the author of `SomeAttribute`, and you want *all* applications of that attribute to be conditional, then you can apply the `Conditional` attribute on the type declaration itself:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
[System.AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class SomeAttribute : Attribute
{
    ...
```

If you do not have the source for `SomeAttribute`, or you do not want it to be all-or-nothing, then preprocessor statements are all that is left as far as what is built-in.

Comment: This is kind of what I figured. This isn't my attribute in this case so I will end up having to wrap it up an a preprocessor it appears. I didn't think about applying a class overall so that was still definitely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

#### No, I don not think so.

If you want to include code that is compiled conditionally you have to use these `#if, #else, #elif #endif` compiler directives, there is no absolute way to do it without it.

You can even use the `ConditionalAttribute` on ur Attribute class, but it gets compiled into the assembly, but later gets optimized by the `JIT` compiler.

---

This should help you understand : [How does the Conditional attribute work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23830822/how-does-the-conditional-attribute-work) and [Omitting code: Any difference between Conditional Attribute and pre-processing directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969841/omitting-code-any-difference-between-conditional-attribute-and-pre-processing-d)

Comment: "but it gets compiled into the assembly, but later gets optimized by the JIT compiler." what does that mean?

Comment: @vcsjones - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23830822/how-does-the-conditional-attribute-work

Comment: That is for method calls, not attributes. When `Conditional` is on an attribute type declaration, the attribute does not appear in the resulting metadata *at all* if there is no conditional compilation symbol that matches the `Conditional` attribute.